# filtering orderList with multiple filter searchCriteria in 'AND' logic

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, filter, search-criteria

I am trying to filter the order list based on two filters.

So far, all of my attempts failed and didn't work. The filter is not working properly and it returns very first order in list of orders in admin panel. It doesn't care about the status or post value of the filter.
I tried to do the filter based on [magento 2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html#filter-group) 
Any idea?

```
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder        
) {
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->_order = $order;
    $this->_filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->_filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;    
}

/**
* Save order - set as handled
*
* @param {Collection} list of orders
*/
public function setOrdersAsRead($orders){

    foreach($orders as $order){

        $order->setPost('1');
        $order->setStatus('complete');
        $this->_orderRepository->save($order);
    }
}



/**
* Find orders where the `post` field is 0
*
* @return {Array} $orders
*/
public function getOrders() {

    $filter1 = $this->_filterBuilder
          ->setField('post')
          ->setValue('0')
          ->setConditionType('eq')
          ->create();

     $filterGroup1 = $this->_filterGroupBuilder;
     $filterGroup1->setFilters([$filter1]);

     $filter2 = $this->_filterBuilder
         ->setField('status')
         ->setValue('canceled')
         ->setConditionType('neq')
         ->create();

     $filterGroup2 = $this->_filterGroupBuilder;
     $filterGroup2->setFilters([$filter2]);

     $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder;
     $searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup1, $filterGroup2])->create();

    $orderList = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria->create());

    return $orderList;
}
```

Comment: use only `$searchCriteria`, no need to use $searchCriteria->create() in the `getList` function

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR the change caused fatal error

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor::getList() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria,

Comment: have you tried like this `$this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)` ?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR yes

Comment: can you post full exception message

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor::getList() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria, instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder given, called in /var/www/MYSITE/vendor/MYSITE/posti/Helpers/Orders.php on line 117 and defined in /var/www/MYSITE/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Model/OrderRepository/Interceptor.php:33 Stack trace: #0

Comment: /var/www/MYSITE/vendor/MYSITE/posti/Helpers/Orders.php(117): Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository\Interceptor->getList(Object(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder)) #1 /var/www/MYSITE/vendor/MYSITE/posti/Helpers/Orders.php(469): MYSITE\Posti\Helpers\Orders->getOrders() #2 /var/www/MYSITE/vendor/MYSITE/posti/Controller/Integration/Integration.php(30): MYSITE\Posti\Helpers\Orders->orderList() #3 /var/www/MYSITE/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): MYSITE\Posti\Cont in /var/www/MYSITE/var/generation/Magento/Sales/Model/OrderRepository/Interceptor.php on line 33

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68450/discussion-between-meenakshisundaram-r-and-k185).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some catch and try and also tnx to @MeenakshiSundaramR, this was the fix for my problem,I changed the getOrders() in this way

```
    public function getOrders() {

    $filter1 = $this->_filterBuilder
    ->setField('post')
    ->setValue('0')
    ->setConditionType('eq')
    ->create();

    $filterGroup1 = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->setFilters([$filter1])->create();

    $filter2 = $this->_filterBuilder
        ->setField('status')
        ->setValue('canceled')
        ->setConditionType('neq')
        ->create();

    $filterGroup2 = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->setFilters([$filter2])->create();

    $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup1, $filterGroup2]);

    $orderList = $this->_orderRepository->getList($searchCriteriaBuilder->create());

    return $orderList;
}
```

Comment: how to filter only processing and complete orders?