# How to get pending products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, onepage-checkout, order-status

Here I added one product per customer function works well. But if payment is canceled or pending also this works. I need this to work only when order status is pending or canceled  but shouldn't work when status is processing or success.

```
 $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($match);
        $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();


    if (in_array(77, $categoryIds)) //if its category is schemes
      {

    echo "<h3>You have repeated items In Cart, try adding Differnt products</h3>";
      $block->deleteQuoteItems();
      }
```

Comment: you can use filter in this situation, so you should filter the orders and then you can get what you are looking for.
Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200726/filtering-orderlist-with-multiple-filter-searchcriteria-in-and-logic
Here I tried to filter the orders based on two rules with logical AND. You can use similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

To get pending products order follow the below code:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');
foreach($orderDatamodel as $orderDatamodel1){
    $getid =  $orderDatamodel1->getData("increment_id");
    $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($getid);
    //echo "<pre>";
    $getorderdata = $orderData->getData();
    $orderItems = $orderData->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($orderItems as $orderItems){
        print_r($orderItems->getData());
    }
}
```